# Select the maximum element of each row in an array-like column in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

As title, my data looks like this:
[0, 0.1, 0.2] in every row in that column (It's not guaranteed that max value is always the last one). I need to get the max value in this array. However, when trying:

```
SELECT *, "element_at"(array_sort(array_agg(CAST(i AS DOUBLE))), "cardinality"(velocity)) max_velocity
FROM table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(velocity) AS t(i)
```

I got this: `Column 'table.column1' not in GROUP BY clause`. Is there a way out?

Comment: Please post the data as text and also what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be a json. If it is true you can try to process it like one - cast to array of maps, then [`transform`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform) the array and find [`array_max`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_max):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (json_val) AS (
    VALUES  (json '[{"N":"0"}, {"N":"1.1"}]')

) 

--query
select array_max(transform(arr, js_map -> cast(js_map['N'] as double)))
from(
    select cast(json_val as array(map(varchar, varchar))) arr
    from dataset
)
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 1.1 |